# Delete one cell from one row in a SQL Server table with WHERE condition

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I have a SQL Server database table `Person` and it has a column `PersonPhoto` (data is binary picture) and I need to delete data from this column `where PersonCode = '386086'`. How can I do this with T-SQL?

Comment: By cell/field I assume you mean column? Column is the RDBMS term.

Comment: You obviously can't delete a column, you can only delete rows, but you can update a column to `null`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't `delete` single column from the table, either you should delete one row or update particular column.

Try simple `Update`

```
UPDATE Person 
SET PersonPhoto = NULL
WHERE PesronCode='386086'.
```

Or go with row `Delete`

```
DELETE FROM Person WHERE PesronCode='386086'.
```

Comment: I mentioned that it should be nullable.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot delete data from just a field in SQL Server, but you can update the field to null (if it's nullable).

```
Update Person Set PersonPhoto = NULL where PesronCode='386086'
```